# Transfer of spool file (printer file) from one AS400 system to another

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a requirement where I have to send spool files produced in test AS400 system to production AS400 system. I have been provided with the outq of the production system.

Can any one tell me the process on how to do this transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of FTP and CL commands.

CPYSPLF is used to copy a spooled file to physical file.

```
crtpf  qgpl/splf133 rcdlen(133) 
CPYSPLF FILE(QSYSPRT)           
        TOFILE(QGPL/SPLF133) SPLNBR(*LAST)           
        MBROPT(*REPLACE) CTLCHAR(*FCFC)
```

FTP PUT to send the physical file to the remote system

```
put  /qsys.lib/qgpl.lib/splf133.file /qsys.lib/qgpl.lib/splf133.file (REPLACE
```

Write a CL program named qgpl/UTL0010C on the remote system that copies the spooled file data from the physical file back to a spooled file

```
OVRPRTF FILE(QSYSPRT) CTLCHAR(*FCFC)  OUTQ(PRODLIB/REPORTS)
cpyf  qgpl/splf133  qsysprt
```

Use the FTP RCMD sub command to run the UTL0010C program on the remote system to copy the physical file back to a spooled file.

```
quote rcmd call qgpl/utl0010c
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for the reply. I found another command from IBM site called SNDTCPSPLF... I was able to send the spool using this command, it's quite straight forward and only one step execution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regular requirement, you also could create a "remote outq", akin to UNIX *lpd*. Both TCP and SNA is a valid transport protocol.

See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-remote-output-queue-rmtoutq) for a collection of links to several IBM documentation pages.

Comment: If you're satisfied with your own answer, please mark it as your preferred answer. So the question is no longer "open". Thanks!